# Saving data in application class error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put my list of custom objects in the application class to access my data in multiple activities. But something doesn't work, and I don't know what's going wrong.

This is what I'm doing:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open("myJsonFile.json");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {

     List<JJsonResponse> jsonResponse = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<List<JJsonResponse>>() { });
     Log.i("tijdlog","einde parsing" );
     final  List<JJsonResponse> myGlobalVariable = jsonResponse;
      ((ApplicationController)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(myGlobalVariable);
```

where JJsonResponse is some custom object. Without the last part, everything worked just fine.

My ApplicationController class:

```
    public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    private List<JJsonResponse> venueController;

    public List<JJsonResponse> getGlobalVariable() {
        return venueController;
    }

    public void setGlobalVariable(List<JJsonResponse> globalVariable) {
        this.venueController = globalVariable;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }
}
```

when running the program crashes.
error log:

```
07-20 14:06:09.487: W/dalvikvm(6668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jacksonrecipes.testapp/com.jacksonrecipes.testapp.Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at com.jacksonrecipes.testapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:52)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
07-20 14:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
```

I made the variable final cause I thought it might have something to do with that, but that didn't work. Does anyone know what the uncaught exception might be and how to solve my problem?

edit: Forgot to show my manifest, I don't know if that's right so I added it:

```
   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".ApplicationController" 
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the name of your Application in your Android project's `Manifest.xml` to `ApplicationController` something like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationController"
......
```

**EDIT** You have supplied two applications in your manifest. Change your Manifest from this:

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<application 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:name=".ApplicationController" 
/>
```

to this:

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name=".ApplicationController"  >
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

And i think you will be ok

Comment: Actually i did define the name as application, but i forgot to show it. Thank you for pointing that out, my mistake might be there. I edited my post.

Comment: Great, it worked perfect.Thank you for the fast and accurate answer.